# How do I remove all desktop-related packages, leaving server only?

Tags: uninstall

I've got a VPS server, on which I surprisingly find packages like `bluez` or `thunderbird-gnome-support` or `firefox` or `libqt4`.

Do I have to list all the packages like in "[How to delete all desktop environments except Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181356/how-to-delete-all-desktop-environments-except-unity)"?

Comment: That one doesn't include `ubuntu-desktop`, and doesn't relate to desktop-universal desktop-only packages like `firefox`.

Comment: [Remove packages to tranform ubuntu Desktop to Server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73219/remove-packages-to-tranform-ubuntu-desktop-to-server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove x11 and everything that uses it:

```
apt-get purge libx11.* libqt.*
```

Comment: Take care with this and review the dependent packages that will be removed carefully because even on server installation, some program may need X11 libraries. I think mainly to image manipulation toolkit like ImageMagick used by many Web Gallery sites. Also, this REGEX will remove not only **libx11** related libraries but also **libxml** libraries that may definetly needed on a server. So for me `apt-get purge libx11*` would a better proposal.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Tasksel** It is a a tool that install/removes packages as per the type of system you require.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel

Comment: `tasksel -t remove ubuntu-desktop` shows that it does not remove Firefox, xorg, etc.

Comment: Yes you can also do it from the command line with `sudo tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop`. But if you do `dpkg -l libx11-6` or `dpkg -l firefox` afterwards you will see that those packages are still installed, so tasksel is not removing all of the desktop packages.

Comment: To get from ubuntu 14.04 desktop to server I ran `sudo tasksel` then select from the available options **Basic Ubuntu Server** I unselected the **Ubuntu Desktop** then **tab** to ok. It removed all of my std desktop and only installed/left me with a server installation. I have not used the `tasksel -t remove` before only the terminal gui. I think that you are left with xorg etc.. as removing the ubuntu destop and not selecting the server option does not remove the x-windows system leaving only server cli. x-windows system requires xorg and firefox can be run from the x-windows system.

Comment: I just tested this, selecting *Basic Ubuntu Server* and deselecting *Ubuntu desktop* exactly as you described, and it did not remove firefox or the x11 libraries.