# How to remove/stop desktop component from the server?

Tags: 14.04, server, .desktop

I found that my ubuntu server is displaying GUI on boot.

How to remove this? This is headless server and there is not reason to spend resources for GUI.

Simultaneously I wish to keep virtual stuff like vncserver and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484095/how-do-i-remove-all-desktop-related-packages-leaving-server-only.). In particular,the command `sudo tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop` may be what you're looking for. There are other commands that the above link leads to that give some other options as well.